# Masterless Puppet and Cannot collect exported resources without storeconfigs being set warnings

Tags: puppet

I am trying out a masterless process for setting up an OpenStack cloud.  I use the puppetlabs-haproxy (v1.5.0) module for setting up HAProxy. When I run my puppet manifest for the controller node like so ...

```
puppet apply -e 'include controller'
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: You cannot collect exported resources without storeconfigs being set; the collection will be ignored at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/haproxy/manifests/balancermember/collect_exported.pp:7:3
```

I have tried setting storeconfigs to true  like this:

```
puppet config set storeconfigs true
```

But that results in this error:

```
Error: Cached facts for aos-mgmt-01 failed: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts
Error: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts
Error: Could not run: Could not retrieve facts for aos-mgmt-01: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts
```

I guess I can just ignore the warning but does anyone know what I can do to correct or suppress the warning?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot do exported resources without a PuppetDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppetlabs haproxy module is collecting exported ressource (like this : https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-haproxy/blob/master/manifests/balancermember/collect_exported.pp#L7)

You need a puppetdb to collect exported resources, so your warning is normal.
You can either ignore it, or use a module that doesn't need exported resources.